# Do I need to use multiple managedObjectContexts when saving data downloaded with AFNetworking?

Tags: multithreading, core-data, afnetworking

Some background on what I'm doing:

I download a CSV file from a server containing data on a number of gadgets. Then use a CSV parser to parse the data into an array of NSDictionaries. Once done, the code below writes the information held in the dictionaries to core data.

A quick explanation of what the code below is doing:

- Fetch all existing core data items
- For each dictionary, check if the product code matches one that's already in core data
- If there's no match, create a new Gadget entity and save it's data
- If there is a match, update it with the latest info
- Use AFNetworking to download the user manual (zip file) for the gadget if the gadget is new or the existing manual is out of date. The manual is created as a separate entity with a relationship back to the gadget (I've done this in case there's ever a need to save multiple manuals).

The first time the app executes this it works fine (i.e. it has to create all new gadgets and download manuals for each). If I update the manual for a gadget on the server and run the app again I get the error (I've marked the line in the code):

> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'theGadget' between objects in different contexts

The entities are both created on the same MOC so I'm not sure why the error would appear. At any rate, I'm led to believe from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485499/is-afnetworking-with-coredata-thread-safe) that AFNetworking's callback is on the main thread so I'm fine using the one MOC. Perhaps I've made another error, or there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do...?

```
-(void)populateCoreDataWithServerData {

    // Fetch all the existing info from core data
    theItems = [self loadFromDatabase:@"Gadgets" andSortDescriptor:nil];

    int row = 0;

    // Cycle through each entry in the parsed CSV data.
    for (NSDictionary *itemDictionary in theItemsInCSV) {

        // Check to see if we've downloaded this item previously.
        Gadgets *gadget;
        bool foundIt = FALSE;
        bool needToUpdateZip = TRUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < [theItems count]; ++i) {

            // Check if we have downloaded it already. If so, update as the item in core data with any new data.
            if ([[[theItems objectAtIndex:i] productCode] isEqualToString:[itemDictionary objectForKey:@"Product Code"]]) {

                foundIt = TRUE;
                gadget = [theItems objectAtIndex:i];

                NSLog(@"Found this item in the local database. Won't be downloading it again.");

                // Check if the zip file with the instruction manual needs updating.
                if ([[[theItems objectAtIndex:i] zipURL] isEqualToString:[itemDictionary objectForKey:@"Manual Zip"]]) {
                    NSLog(@"The zip file is the same or non-existant, no need to update.");
                    needToUpdateZip = FALSE;
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"The zip file is different. Will download");
                }
            }
        }

        // If we haven't downloaded it before, create a new item. We'll update the fields in that.
        if (foundIt == FALSE) {
            gadget = (Gadgets *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Gadget" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            NSLog(@"Didn't find this item in the local database. Had better download it.");
        }

        // Update all the fields.
        [gadget setName:[itemDictionary objectForKey:@"gadget name"]];
        //Set some more attributes (product code etc)


        // Download gadget manual (zip file) if it exists
        if (needToUpdateZip == TRUE) {  // Check if there's a URL in there

            // Create a temp folder
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self tempDirectory]) {  // Use Formidible Key as in identifier rather than the Product Code as the Form Key never has any spaces in it.

                NSError* error;
                if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[self tempDirectory] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Directory created");
                }
            }

            NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Temp%i.zip", row];
            NSString *fileNameWithPath = [[self tempDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

            // Download the zip
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[itemDictionary objectForKey:@"Manual Zip"]]];
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

            operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:fileNameWithPath append:NO];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", [self tempDirectory]);

                // Save the individual files to core data.
                Manuals *manual = (ARData *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manuals" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                [manual setTheGadget:gadget];  // ERROR APPEARS HERE  **********************************
                // Extract the zip file and set some attributes
            }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Download didn't work. Error: %@", error);
                 }
             ];

            [operation start];
        }

        ++row;
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think this is a core data question; your AFNetworking code looks fine.  Have you set a breakpoint before your calls to  `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` and made sure `self.managedObjectContext` points to the same address in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've checked, and the address for self.managedObjectContext is the same at each location.

Comment: I can't give you exact solution for your issue (that looks very strange for me) but you can use this method https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html. You code will look like `NSManagedObjectID *gadgetId = gadget.objectID;[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                Manuals *manual = // create manual
                [manual setTheGadget:[self.managedObjectContext objectWithId:gadgetId]]
            }`

Answer (score 0):

My workaround  for this when updating existing data was to fetch existing Manual entities associated with the gadget and overwrite their data, rather than delete the Manual entities and recreate.

It's not a genuine solution, so if you've got an idea of what's wrong with the code above please let me know!